# minor ii-7 moving to I-6

Tags: chord-progressions, voice-leading

In traditional hymn writing, can I move from a ii-7 in root position to the I chord in first inversion in the middle of my hymn, then continue to the V as a half cadence?

Comment: The key of the piece is irrelevant to the voice leading principles applied, but the question is a good one!

Comment: I'm not sure I could provide the answer you're looking for but it may be useful to clarify if you are referring to a I chord in first inversion or a I major or minor 6 chord.  In case this isn't clear, first inversion, from bass up in C major/minor would be E, G, C, or Eb, G, C, and a major or minor 6 chord would be C, E, G, A or C, Eb, G, A.

Comment: When I say I chord I’m referring to B flat as the hymn is in B flat.

Answer (score 1):

It's not common. I have seen ii7 to I63 to ii65 to V. Returning to I63 would make the tonic a neighbor chord which doesn't cause problems. The ii7 to I63 to ii65 makes the tonic a passing chord. No problems if the voice leading is correct.

Comment: I have the ii7 not stepping down but keeping the B flat in soprano as a I63 then moving to a IV and IVM7 to a 4-3 sus on the V to half cadence at the V.  Is that going to be acceptable in a traditional hymn writing contest (world wide contest) ?

Comment: @ttw Great response. In this style, ii7 will only move to I6 as a part of a larger predominant prolongation.